# Pass AWS SM Secret Key to Lambda Environment with CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am having some trouble getting a specific Secrets Manager Secret key value to pass it to my lambda through CDK.

After some time I finally realized that my `SecretValue`  is only resolved when I actually deploy this to lambda, and not while running local through SAM CLI.
By doing

```
cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager(secretId).toString()
```

I get something like `"{\"apiKey\":\"sdfsdf-sdfsdf-sddsf\"}"`, but I want to rather have the apiKey directly.
Unfortunately, in my CDK code, I cannot `JSON:parse(...secretsManager(..).toString())`  as this will only be resolved once deployed. Before, the value is simply:
`{{resolve:secretsmanager:apiKey:SecretString:::}}` (which seems to be a Token: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tokens.html)

So I guess I would need some way to tell CDK how to use the rendered value, maybe by passing a callback that transforms the rendered result - is that possible?
Are there any other tools I can use in my CDK setup that allow me to receive a specific key from a secret so that I can pass it to lambda directly?

I hope the problem is understandable. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [Secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-secretsmanager.Secret.html). You can use any of the static `from` methods to get the secret. From there you can use the [secretValueFromJson](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-secretsmanager.Secret.html#secretwbrvaluewbrfromwbrjsonjsonfield) method to get the value.

Example (secret for Postgres db):

```js
import * as secretsmanager from '@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager';

const dbSecret = secretsmanager.Secret.fromSecretNameV2(this, 'db-secret', 'db-secret-name');
const dbUser = dbSecret.secretValueFromJson('username').toString();
const dbPass = dbSecret.secretValueFromJson('password').toString();
const dbName = dbSecret.secretValueFromJson('dbname').toString();
```

Comment: what if the secret is a plaintext?

Comment: Seems no longer to work in 2022, please see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

### in 2022

Using `.toString()` on Secrets seems no longer accepted without calling `.unsafeUnwrap()` first.
As far as [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_core.SecretValue.html#unsafewbrunwrap) goes:

> If you **don't call** this method, using the secret value directly in a string context or as a property value somewhere will produce an error.

For me, it produced the error on `cdk deploy`:

> Resolution error: Synthing a secret value to Resources(...) Using a SecretValue here risks exposing your secret. Only pass SecretValues to constructs that accept a SecretValue property, or call
> AWS Secrets Manager directly in your runtime code. Call 'secretValue.unsafeUnwrap()' if you understand and accept the risks..

### Solution

1. as the message suggests try to use frameworks, which accept a SecretValue, or if you don't have the chance (as in my case I am trying to use Prisma, and [it doesn't accept it yet](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7534))
2. use `.unsafeUnwrap()`. Like:

```
const getValueFromSecret = (secret: ISecret, key: string): string => {
  return secret.secretValueFromJson(key).unsafeUnwrap()
}

// usage (e.g. in Lambda stack)
const password = getValueFromSecret(secret, 'password')
```

Answer (score 0):

python version

```
environment_variables = secretsmanager.Secret.from_secret_complete_arn(
        self,
        "environment_variables",
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1234:secret:my-keys",
    )

lambda = _lambda.Function(
        self, "MyLambda",
        function_name="my-function",
        runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
        handler="lambda_function.lambda_handler",
        timeout=cdk.Duration.seconds(3),
        architecture=_lambda.Architecture.ARM_64,
        code=_lambda.Code.from_asset(os.path.join(dirname, '../app_lambdas/my_lambda')),
        role=my_lambda_role,
        environment={
            "API_KEY": environment_variables.secret_value_from_json('api-key').unsafe_unwrap()
        },
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this for Parameter Store with AWS SDK, here's an extract from my stack.ts:

```
import { SSM } from 'aws-sdk'

const ssmSDK = new SSM()

async function fetchParam(name: string): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const param = await ssmSDK
      .getParameter({
        Name: name,
        WithDecryption: true,
      })
      .promise()
    if (!param.Parameter || !param.Parameter.Value) {
      throw new Error(`${name} parameter not found!`)
    }
    return param.Parameter.Value
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`failed to fetch ${name} parameter!`)
  }
}

export async function buildSearchServiceStack(
  scope: cdk.App,
  id: string,
  props?: cdk.StackProps
): Promise<cdk.Stack> {
  const stack = new cdk.Stack(scope, id, props)

  const [jwtSecret, elasticPassword] = await Promise.all([
    fetchParam(`/shared/jwt/SECRET`),
    fetchParam('/shared/elasticsearch/URL')])
// ..
```